# gentelellaShiny conflicts with other packages (formattable, highcharter for instance)

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, gentelella

I'm developping a Shinyapp based on the gentelella template using the `gentelellaShiny` package.

However when I add plots or tables built with the `highcharter` or `formattable` packages the app is showing an empty page. The problem seems to be related to a conflict between the jquery version used to build the gentelella template and the jquery version used in the `formattable` and `highcharter` packages.

Is there an easy trick to upgrade the jquery version in the folder of the gentellaShiny package (`C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\gentelellaShiny`) or would it break all its functions ?

Any solutions/advices would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy trick, the README in gentellaShiny says "gentellelaShiny still depends on an older version of jQuery (1.x...) whereas shiny has 3.x...". This suggests to me that we cannot simply replace the jQuery version without breaking gentallyShiny's functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I should forget using gentelella then :crying:

Comment: Someone seems to have been able to figure out how to make it work but that person is not using the gentelellaShiny package but the template instead. Don't you think it could be feasible with the package ?
Topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703549/highcharter-integration-in-r-shiny-html-template-based-application